# Paste PDF image into Pyplot figure

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

How can I plot the image from a PDF file into a Pyplot figure (e.g. with `plt.imshow`, or inside some container I can add with `ax.add_artist`)?

---

Methods that do not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imread('file.pdf')
```

(Source: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765056/combine-picture-and-plot-with-python-matplotlib), where it works for PNG files.)

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('file.pdf')
```

(Source: [this doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html), but again, it [doesn't work for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048266/python-pil-cant-open-pdfs-for-some-reason); the question links a library to read PDFs but the doc shows no obvious way to add them to a Pyplot figure.)

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437381/using-a-pdf-image-inside-a-subplot-in-matplotlib) exists, but the answers solve the problem without actually loading a PDF file.

Comment: Neither matplotlib, nor pillow (which matplotlib would use under the hood for such tasks) are capable of reading pdf as far as I know. The usual strategy is to convert your pdf to a readable format like png and read that in, e.g. via `imread`.  There are many tools for conversion. Personally I would use inkscape. But there are also python tools available, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/python-extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826854/python-wand-convert-pdf-to-png-disable-transparent-alpha-channel).

Comment: why not convert your file to readable format?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called PyMuPDF that makes this job a lot easier.

### Scraping PDF images into PIL Image

1. To scrape the individual images out of each page tutorials can be found [here](https://aliarefwriorr.medium.com/extract-all-images-from-pdf-in-python-cda3dc195abd) and [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/extract-images-from-pdf-python/) on how to convert them into PIL format.
2. If the intention is to grab an entire PDF page or pages, the `page.get_pixmap()` documented [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#rendering-a-page), can do this.

The snippet below shows how to iterate through and grab each page of a PDF as a `PIL.Image`

```
import io
import fitz
from PIL import Image

file = 'myfile.pdf'
pdf_file = fitz.open(file)

# in case there is a need to loop through multiple PDF pages
for page_number in range(len(pdf_file)):
    page = pdf_file[page_number]
    rgb = page.get_pixmap()
    pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(rgb.tobytes()))

    # display code or image manipulation here for each page #
```

### Displaying scraped PDF Image

In either case, once there is a `PIL.Image` object, such as the `pil_image` variable above, the `show()` function can display it (and does so differently depending on the OS). However, if the preference is to use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` the `PIL.Image` must be converted to RGB first.

Snippet to display `PIL.Image` with `pyplot.imshow`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(pil_image.convert('RGB'))
```